# Can I save my Ganache private blockchain instead starting a new one every time?

Tags: private-blockchain, ganache

Every time I turn my computer off or even change settings on Ganache (I need to restart) I lose the state of the blockchain and it creates a new one, I have to redeploy my contracts, etc.

Is there a way to keep the same blockchain every time I open Ganache?

How should I proceed if I want to keep track of my private blockchain?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the solution: --db: Specify a path to a directory to save the chain database. If a database already exists, the TestRPC will initialize that chain instead of creating a new one.

from: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli